# Placing a div on another div

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML code and CSS code.

```css
#header {
  height: 75px;
}
#right {
  height: 75px;
  width: 700px;
  float: right;
}
#top {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}
#bottom {
  height: 800px;
  background-color: silver;
}
#main {
  height: 850px;
  width: 950px;
  background-color: #F3ECEA;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css">

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id=header>
      
      <div id="left"></div>
      <div id="right"></div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div></div>
  
  <div id="top"></div>
  <div id="bottom"></div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

I am trying to place the `#main` div on the center of the webpage and also it should be over the `#top` and `#bottom` divs. I've tried `z-index` but it didn't work. While using `z-index` I was able to place the `#main` div on `#top` and `#bottom` div's but `margin:auto` isn't working. While using the top and bottom attributes for `position:absolute` I was able to place the `#main` div but resizing the window is making it different. I want the `#main` div to be over the `#bottom` and `#top` division and also on the center of the page even after resizing the page.

Comment: Please share the image how would you expect it to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

z-index should work to manage the divs with respect to one being ahead of the other. The reason your centering and other aspects changes when you change screen resolution, i.e. minimize, etc is because you have defined all of your css with px and not percentage. Change your margin, etc to percentages and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to place `#main` div above top/bottom divs, you simply add a `z-index` of 1 to it.

To center `#main` with absolute position, you need to specify a 0 value for Left and Right properties and add auto for margin.

[See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y94mhoaj/2/)

Answer (score 0):

your code is collapsing because of your float you applied, that's why changing things isn't giving you the desired effect. Open your dev tools(F12) in chrome and you can inspect the elements to see where they are sitting.

I would suggest adding clearfix to your parent div if you are going to float.

to be honest I am a little confused where you want your divs to be, could you post a picture?

Comment: iam trying to design the whatsapp web page. we have a main div in which we chat which is loacted on the center of the window over two more div's.

Answer (score 0):

To place #main over #top and #bottom just use `z-index`. Higher z-index for #main. Lower value for #top and #bottom.

To center the #main within the page use,

```
margin-top: calc(50vh - 425px);
margin-left: calc(50vw - 475px);
```

vh stands for viewport height, and vw for viewport width. calc() function will dynamically calculate top and left margin values when the window size changes.

**Reference:**

- More about CSS units here - [CSS Units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).
- More about CSS calc function here - [CSS calc() Function](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp)